# Verify XML Digital Signature but reference digest is invalid

Tags: java, digital-signature

I have 2 reference to check digest - data and timer object.
reference digest 1 for data check valid, but reference digest 2 for timer invalid.

**XML Timer object like this**

```
<Object Id="SigningTime-y7j1dbyn0mizsgz1u87newzwhpravuhj">
    <SignatureProperties xmlns="">
        <SignatureProperty Target="#Signature-uvyfweshgf1hwyekbhdmprhrueucfryu">
            <SigningTime>2023-04-21T14:01:11</SigningTime>
        </SignatureProperty>
    </SignatureProperties>
</Object>
```

**Code to gen Digest**

```
private String getDigestForRemoteTimer(Document inputNode, String signingTagName) throws Exception {
        Node nodeToBeHash = inputNode.getElementsByTagName(signingTagName).item(0); 
        Canonicalizer c14n = usingNS ? Canonicalizer.getInstance(Canonicalizer.ALGO_ID_C14N_EXCL_OMIT_COMMENTS)
                : Canonicalizer.getInstance(Canonicalizer.ALGO_ID_C14N_OMIT_COMMENTS);
        byte[] transformed = c14n.canonicalizeSubtree(nodeToBeHash);    
        return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(DigestCreator.digest(transformed, hashAlgo));
    }
```

**XML Reference**

```
<Reference URI="#SigningTime-y7j1dbyn0mizsgz1u87newzwhpravuhj">
    <Transforms>
        <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315"/>
    </Transforms>
    <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
    <DigestValue>LNtFIlPRNK6sxTU82H7MfG/lXRg=</DigestValue>
</Reference>
```

But when i check Verify XML Digital Signature, it has **Reference digest is invalid because the computed digest differs from the digest in the XML**. So what's problem in this? And how can I fix it?